# Converting day datetime to timestamp in Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a datetime data in a table in Snowflake and I want to convert it into a timestamp

```
|-----------------------------------------|
|                Date                     |
|-----------------------------------------|
|      Wed 22 Mar 2022 12:51:21 -0500     |
|      Sun 28 Apr 2022 02:21:19 -0500     |
|      Mon 21 Mar 2021 18:31:59 -0500     |
|      Fri 12 Jan 2022 19:41:46 -0500     |
|      Thu 09 Feb 2022 23:51:17 -0500     |
|      Tue 17 May 2021 07:61:07 -0500     |
|      Wed 07 Oct 2022 01:71:01 -0500     |
|-----------------------------------------|
```

The output I want is:

```
|------------------------------------|
|                Date                |
|------------------------------------|
|      03/22/2022 12:51:21 -0500     |
|      04/28/2022 02:21:19 -0500     |
|      03/21/2021 18:31:59 -0500     |
|      01/12/2022 19:41:46 -0500     |
|      02/09/2022 23:51:17 -0500     |
|      05/17/2021 07:61:07 -0500     |
|      10/07/2022 01:71:01 -0500     |
|------------------------------------|
```

The methods I tried:

```
select to_date(date) from my_table

select to_date(date, 'mm/dd/yyyy h24:mi:ss') from my_table

select to_timestamp_tz(date) from my_table
```

etc.. None of the above conversions worked

Comment: What is the datatype of the column?

Comment: @NickW It's varchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the correct [formatting](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/date-time-input-output.html#about-the-format-specifiers-in-this-section) tokens, your valid datetime strings can be parsed. Depending if you what to have or not have timezone part on the timestamp, indicates which function you should use.

```
SELECT column1
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_tz(column1, 'dy dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss tzhtzm') as tz
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(column1, 'dy dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss tzhtzm') as default
    ,TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_ntz(column1, 'dy dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss tzhtzm') as ntz
FROM VALUES
    ('Wed 22 Mar 2022 12:51:21 -0500'),
    ('Sun 28 Apr 2022 02:21:19 -0500'),
    ('Mon 21 Mar 2021 18:31:59 -0500'),
    ('Fri 12 Jan 2022 19:41:46 -0500'),
    ('Thu 09 Feb 2022 23:51:17 -0500'),
    ('Tue 17 May 2021 07:61:07 -0500'),
    ('Thu 07 Oct 2022 01:71:01 -0500')
```

gives:

| COLUMN1 | TZ | DEFAULT | NTZ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wed 22 Mar 2022 12:51:21 -0500 | 2022-03-22 12:51:21.000 -0500 | 2022-03-22 12:51:21.000 | 2022-03-22 12:51:21.000 |
| Sun 28 Apr 2022 02:21:19 -0500 | 2022-04-28 02:21:19.000 -0500 | 2022-04-28 02:21:19.000 | 2022-04-28 02:21:19.000 |
| Mon 21 Mar 2021 18:31:59 -0500 | 2021-03-21 18:31:59.000 -0500 | 2021-03-21 18:31:59.000 | 2021-03-21 18:31:59.000 |
| Fri 12 Jan 2022 19:41:46 -0500 | 2022-01-12 19:41:46.000 -0500 | 2022-01-12 19:41:46.000 | 2022-01-12 19:41:46.000 |
| Thu 09 Feb 2022 23:51:17 -0500 | 2022-02-09 23:51:17.000 -0500 | 2022-02-09 23:51:17.000 | 2022-02-09 23:51:17.000 |
| Tue 17 May 2021 07:61:07 -0500 | null | null | null |
| Thu 07 Oct 2022 01:71:01 -0500 | null | null | null |

because that last two are invalid times, if you correct the time to be in the valid range, the day being wrong is ignored.